# Compare Two SQL identical Table to find missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on SQL 2008. I have two identical tables with same column names.

On Table2, i am missing some records. Some records got deleted in the Table2.

I have to compare Table1 and Table2 and retrieve only missing records from table1.

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` and `WHEN IS NULL`, assuming that tables have a primary key

Comment: can you please frame the query.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for `IS NULL` like below. `where t2.col2 is null` will be `TRUE` only when there are records in table1 which are not present in table2. Which is what you are looking for. [This is a sample code and have no resemblance with your original query]

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.some_column = t2.some_column
where t2.col2 is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use SQL Except. There is no Join involved.

```
Select * from dbo.TableA
Except
Select * from dbo.TableB
```

In set theory, the difference of sets A, B (A-B) is the set of elements that belong to A and do not belong to B.

Comment: Except syntax is not working as mentioned. It returns all records of Table1

Comment: This compares both tables. I can't see your data. Do they have different keys? If you want to test certain columns then specify them in your select. Also, this example is showing you what belongs to A but not to B. If you want to see what belongs to B but not to A then flip the selects :-)

Comment: @goofyui If it returns rows, then the syntax **is**. It means that every row returned has at a least one column with a different value in the second table

Comment: @lamak, i got that. I have 580 records on Table1 and 571 records on Table2. I need to know only these 9 records. When i use Left Join as mentioned above by giving condition on column name i get a different difference value. I understand that all column has different values. I am looking on row difference.

Comment: @goofyui I don't think you do get it. For `EXCEPT` to give you the results you want, **every single value** of the row has to be the same on both tables

Comment: I believe every single value on Table1 is equal to Table2. Except, missing values will mismatch their ID Column. I can try running Except by ignoring the ID Column

Comment: @goofyui Yes, you can if you list the columns you actually want to compare instead of using `SELECT *`

Comment: i tried running select column_name into (Newtable) from TableA and did it for TableB. Still Except syntax is not returning as expected. Guess, this is because of value difference in the columns

Comment: @goofyui It is because of that. You can actually compare the rows between both tables because you have access to them, so no need to *guess*

Answer (score 0):

With an " not exists", you have a solution :

```
select * from Table1 t1 where not exists (select 1 from Table2 t2  
    where t1.col1 = t2.col1
      and t1.col2 = t2.col2  
      and t1.col3 = t2.col3  
      and ...                 // check here all columns ...
   )
```

There is however a little problem in this solution in the case of null values, which can only be tested via a "IS NOT NULL" or "IS NULL", hence the complementary solution:

```
select * from Table1 t1 where not exists (select 1 from Table2 t2  
    where (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or (t1.col1 IS NULL and t2.col1 IS NULL))
      and (t1.col2 = t2.col2 or (t1.col2 IS NULL and t2.col2 IS NULL))  
      and (t1.col3 = t2.col3 or (t1.col3 IS NULL and t2.col3 IS NULL))  
      and ...                 // check here all columns ...
   )
```